# How to add label to a plot in PopupMenu which does not change the plot size

Tags: gui-construction

I am facing a problem in adding a label to a `PopupMenu`. I have two plots a and b of same size. But when I am adding label to them in `PopupMenu`, it is changing the size of the plot.

When the `Label` size is bigger, it compresses the plot so that it adjust to the `FieldSize` of `PopupMenu`. But I dont want this.

```
 a = Manipulate[
       l = DiscretePlot[Cos[a t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
       ImageSize -> Scaled[1], AspectRatio -> .25, ImageMargins -> 0, 
       ImagePadding -> 0], 
       Mouseover["vertical", Control[{{a, 1, "a Manipulator"}, 1, 20}]], 
       ControlPlacement -> Bottom];
b = Manipulate[q = Graphics[
     DiscretePlot[Sin[g t], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
     PlotStyle -> Orange, AspectRatio -> .25, ImageSize -> Scaled[1], 
     ImageMargins -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0]], {g, 1, 10}];

Grid[{{PopupMenu[
        Dynamic[p], {a ->Labeled[l, (Framed["pop_up_window Plot"]), {Right}, 
                   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]], 
                 b -> Labeled[q, (Framed["mouseover Plot"]), {Right}, 
               LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]]}, 
       FieldSize -> {24, 8}, ImageMargins -> 0, 
       FrameMargins -> 0, ContentPadding -> False, 
       Alignment -> {Center, Center}]}, {Dynamic[p]}}, Spacings -> 20, 
       Alignment -> {Left, Top}]
```

[image]

When I am adding label, then the first plot becomes smaller than the second. I want that `Label` size should not affect the `Plot`size.

Comment: Could you add an image of what you're seeing, and what you *want to see*?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the behaviour you describe.  The plots always have the same size here.  Can you avoid using `Scaled` units in `FieldSize`?  I'm not sure if you're aware that `Scaled` is relative to the notebook width in this case.  Probably this is why I can't reproduce it on a different system.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I have edited `FieldSize` in code. I was not knowing by `Scaled`, it will not work on different systems

Comment: I still can't reproduce it on my system, Jennifer.  This is what I get using your code: http://i.stack.imgur.com/t7kqp.png The plots are the same size.  The labels do get compressed.

Comment: @Ajasja: Yes, so how can I rectify this?

Comment: @Ajasja: Yes, for me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce this behaviour on my system.  The plots always have exactly the same size.  This is what your code produces here:

[image]

But on your system you could try setting the image size explicitly to force a fixed size.  Inside `Labeled`, try replacing `q` by `Show[q, ImageSize -> 100]`.  Do the same for `l`.  Does this fix the problem?

Comment: One more thing how can I set first plot as default?

Comment: @Jennifer To have a default value, you can set a value to `p` before evaluating the `PopupMenu`.  This will be the initial value.  It has to match one of the values that the `PopupMenu` can set to `p`.

Comment: I have tried that too but when I am deploying it in CDF, it is showing p as the output. I want that when I dont select any plot on the popupmenu, then too it should select some plot.